# Exception is not getting caught, while the function was converted into lambda and executed in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

As you can see, the `connect` function, is converting the `_connect` function into a lambda through `convert` and it's getting passed to `run_api` function. The exception thrown in `_connect` is not getting caught by the except in the `run_api` function. Is anything that needs to be done with respect to `lambda`?

The code looks good but still am not able to figure out why the exception is not getting caught incase of failure.

Here is my code.

```
def run_api(function, retry_count):
    count = 0
    while count < retry_count:
        count += 1
        try:
            function()
            return True
        except (BleTestFail, BleTestError):
            if count == retry_count:
                return False


def convert(func):
    return lambda: func


def _connect(self, target_id):
    result = self.device.ble_central.connect(target_id)
    self.logger.debug('Connect output %s', result)

    if result['op'] != 'ok':
        self.logger.error('Connect command execution failed')
        raise ble_utils.BleTestFail('Failed to connect')

    return True

def connect(self, target_ids, retry_count=1):
    connected = []
    unconnected = []
    if not isinstance(target_ids, list):
        target_ids = [target_ids]
    for target_id in target_ids:
        connect_function = ble_utils.convert(self._connect(target_id))
        connect_status = ble_utils.run_api(connect_function, retry_count,
                                           'connecting device %s' % target_id,
                                           self.logger)
        if connect_status:
            connected.append(target_id)
        else:
            unconnected.append(target_id)

    if connected:
        self.logger.info('Connected to %s devices: %s', len(connected), connected)
    if unconnected:
        self.logger.error('Unable to connect %s devices: %s', len(unconnected),
                          unconnected)
    return connected, unconnected
```

Comment: You raise `ble_utils.BleTestFail` but catch `BleTestFail` without qualification. Is the unqualified name available? Are you sure the class was only declared once?

Comment: Are you really calling the function? If `func` is a function, then `lambda: func` just returns this function without calling it. You may want `lambda: func()`. And `ble_utils.convert(self._connect(target_id))` cannot really convert it into a lambda, you are passing the return of `_connect` instead of the function.

Comment: How does `ble_utils.convert` relate to `convert`?

Comment: I don't understand this whole function-to-a-lambda thing. You have a function that returns a  function so to call it you'd have to do `func()()`.

Comment: @Sraw yeah i might be passing the return instead of the function to convert. What exactly i should try now

Comment: `return lambda: func` just nests `func` in an anonymous function — which serves no useful purpose. It just increases overhead of calling `func`. What are you trying to achieve by doing this exactly?

Comment: @martineau I need to wrap _connect into a lambda and pass it to run_api. I need the exception thrown in _connect to be caught in run_api

Comment: As I said, your `convert()` does nothing — but you're not even calling it, so your question makes even less sense. I say the former because calling `ble_utils.convert()` does **not** call the function you have defined in your code by that name.

Comment: @martineau the question - I think! - makes sense once you understand what the actual goal is - which is difficult, but that's because OP seems to lack the necessary vocabulary. I think the only solution is for someone like me to put on the mind-reading hat :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yeah I understood, I should have explained the objective better. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to clarify, we have the example "API" to which we want to provide a *callback*:

```
def run_api(function, retry_count):
    count = 0
    while count < retry_count:
        count += 1
        try:
            function()
            return True
        except (BleTestFail, BleTestError):
            if count == retry_count:
                return False
```

And a method that we want to be called in that API, with a specific argument:

```
class Example:
    # other stuff omitted...

    def _connect(self, target_id):
        result = self.device.ble_central.connect(target_id)
        self.logger.debug('Connect output %s', result)

        if result['op'] != 'ok':
            self.logger.error('Connect command execution failed')
            raise ble_utils.BleTestFail('Failed to connect')

        return True

connection = Example()
```

So now we want to call `run_api` with `connection._connect`, but somehow provide the `target_id` information.

This is called *binding*, and the most elegant way to do it is with the standard library `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

# This is how we can make the `convert` function from before:
def convert(func, param):
    return partial(func, param)
# But there is no point to this, since we can just use `partial` directly.
# There was no hope for the original approach, because you were calling the 
# function ahead of time and passing the returned result to `convert`.

# So, the process looks like this:
# target_id = 1, retry_count = 2
run_api(partial(connection._connect, 1), 2)
```

You *can* make it work with `lambda`, but I don't recommend it - `functools.partial` is more explicit, and elegantly handles more advanced use cases that have some unexpected gotchas (in particular, if you want to make multiple callbacks in a loop; you may find they all unexpectedly bind with the same value, or else you have to use a very ugly workaround). But for the sake of completion, that looks like so:

```
def convert(func, param):
    return lambda: func(param)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and I am going with partial.